# aibo関係のタグの使い分け

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ

最近 [aibo-developer](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aibo-developer) というタグと [aibo-visual-programming](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aibo-visual-programming) というタグができました。

ただ、タグ wiki が書かれておらず、これらがどのような使い分けをされるべきものなのかよく分かっていません。

これらはどのように使うタグなのでしょうか？　最終的にはタグ wiki に説明を書きたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ソニーさんからのお返事がまだのようなので、aiboオーナーとして理解してる範囲ですが。

2018年1月11日にソニー株式会社から新しい犬型ロボット(ERS-1000)が発売されました。
そして2019年11月11日、aiboオーナーを対象として WebAPIが公開され、それに伴い、サポート先に Stackoverflow がリンクされました。
◆aibo-visual-programming はScratch APIによる初心者用。
　http://aibo.sony.jp/fan/visual_programming/
◆aibo-developer は、Python 等、中級者以上用。
　https://developer.aibo.com/jp/
　と別けられています。　
デベロッパーサイトには、「投稿する際は、aibo-developer タグをつけてください。」と書かれています。書かれてはいるのですが、現実問題として、初回は信用度が低く、aibo-developerタグを付けることが出来ませんでした。編集で付けて下さったお陰で、2回目の質問から付けられるようになりました。

aiboサポートさんが時々？回って下さってるようですが。。。皆様にお手数掛けております。
ただ、aiboサポートさんもこちらに入られたのは最近のようで、タグwiki に説明を書けないのは、信用度が足らず書きたくても書けないのだと思います。

タグとリンク元での記載の件につき、オーナーサポート経由で対応下さるよう、お伝えし、担当者に申し送ったとお返事もいただきましたので、もう少しお待ちくださいませ。

Comment: 頂いたご意見を元に、[aibo-developer] と [aibo-visual-programming] のタグwikiを書いてみました。詳細を教えてくださりありがとうございました！

Answer (score 3):

ざっくりとは以下のイメージです。

- [aibo-developer](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aibo-developer) は aibo 関連の開発にまつわる話全般 ( [主にAPI関連](https://developer.aibo.com/jp/home)？)
- [aibo-visual-programming](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aibo-visual-programming) は [Webアプリケーションツールの名称](http://aibo.sony.jp/fan/visual_programming/) のようです。

特に後者はリンク先でスタック・オーバーフローへのリンクにタグとして指定されているみたいです。
([spresense](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spresense) もそうだけど、詳しい注意書きとして "ソニーとは直接関連の無い外部サイトでQAを扱うコミュニティだよ" という情報を記載して欲しいなと思います…)

---

(追記@2020/01/23)
aiboさんのウェブサイトでは修正がかけられ「スタック・オーバーフローは外部サイトである」と周知されています。
https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact#devevisu